# Changing the property of an object in an ObservableCollection using index

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have an `ObservableCollection` inside which I have inserted 3 objects of my class.
After a foreach loop I would like to change the value of a property of that object

```
ObservableCollection<Calendar> Cal = new ObservableCollection<Calendar>
                {
                    new Calendar{DateDay= dayMeno2.ToString(), DateMonth=MonthNowMeno2, Color="Black"},
                    new Calendar{DateDay= dayMeno1.ToString(), DateMonth=MonthNowMeno1, Color="Black"},
                    new Calendar{DateDay= DateTime.Now.Day.ToString(), DateMonth=MonthNow, Color="Black"},
                };

 if (something)
 {
     Cal[2] = ....??? 
 }
```

I would like to change the `Color` property in position 2 but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Elements of collections with indexers are simply accessed directly, just as your code shows. See duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just reference the property

```
Cal[2].Color = "White";
```

note that C# is 0-indexed, so `[2]` is actually the *third* element